# Ruby 1.9.3p0 JSON .to_json method returning "at least contain two octets!" on valid hash

Tags: ruby, json

I am scraping google news and trying to encode a ruby hash into JSON. However, I'm receiving this error using either `to_json` or `MultiJson.dump()`:

```
#<JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!>

data = {"key" => ["values"], "key2" => ["values"].. etc}
```

An example of my hash is located here: [ruby hash I'm trying to encode](https://gist.github.com/Stephenitis/8137475)

Comment: I can't duplicate that error. Your hash on gist contains non-ASCII characters, so you could get errors for that. Your question as is, is invalid. We can't duplicate the problem, which makes it hard to fix it. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." Remove the link to gist, and put a summarized version of your data and code that replicates the problem into your question.

Comment: It appears to have been a ruby 1.9.3p0 error. unsure why currently.